# R function similar to Excel's index-match

Tags: r, match, lookup

I'm sure there is a fairly straight forward solution to my problem. However, my limited R-skills let me down and I didn't come across a suitable solution yet.

I have a matrix A looking like:

```
     Year SIC       alpha  
[1,] 1990  13 -0.08610973 
[2,] 1990  15 -0.02270707  
[3,] 1990  20  0.01273243
[4,] 1990  25 -0.25173402 
[5,] 1991  26 -0.02625965 
[6,] 1991  27 -0.02685330 
....
```

And a matrix B which looks like

```
      46   27   13   37   20   ...
1989  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
1990  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
1991  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I'd like to perform a kind of two-dimensional lookup. I want to paste the values from matrix A's column "alpha" into matrix B, where the row names of B match `A$Year` and the column names of B match `A$SIC`. So basically similar to Excel's Index-match-functions.

The result would look like this:

```
      46   27             13           37   20   ...
1989  NA   NA             NA           NA   NA
1990  NA   NA            -0.08610973   NA   0.01273243
1991  NA   -0.02685330    NA           NA   NA
```

I hope anyone can help me out.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It would help if you made your example reproducible; for example, providing small examples of the two matrices using `dput()`.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep in mind for next time. Roland's solution worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#reproduce data
A <- read.table(text="Year SIC       alpha  
1990  13 -0.08610973 
1990  15 -0.02270707  
1990  20  0.01273243
1990  25 -0.25173402 
1991  26 -0.02625965 
1991  27 -0.02685330", header=TRUE)

B <- read.table(text="      46   27   13   37   20  
1989  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
1990  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
1991  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)

A <- as.matrix(A)
B <- as.matrix(B)

#reshape to long format
Bm <- stack(as.data.frame(B))
Bm$ind <- as.character(Bm$ind)
Bm$year <- rownames(B)

#merge
C <- merge(Bm[, c("ind", "year")], 
           as.data.frame(A), 
           by.x=c("ind", "year"), 
           by.y=c("SIC", "Year"), 
           all.x=TRUE)

#reshape to wide format
library(reshape2)
dcast(C, year~ind)

#  year          13         20         27 37 46
#1 1989          NA         NA         NA NA NA
#2 1990 -0.08610973 0.01273243         NA NA NA
#3 1991          NA         NA -0.0268533 NA NA
```